# EXTJS (5.1.3) How to align the expand tool to the top of an East collapsed to the right panel

Tags: extjs

I have an application with 3 panels: Left (west), Center and Right (east).  The left and right panels are collapsible.  I want the expand tool on the right panel to display at the top of the collapsed panel's side header.  Is there a way to do that?  So far I have failed...

Here's a fiddle showing the problem:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3ppm&view/editor

I have tried looking at the available configs - nothing seems to allow this.  I also tried adding events to intercept the expand and collapse of the panel to try and adjust the tool's position, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Questions here must be self-contained. Please [edit] the code directly into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the tool position by setting some CSS styles to the tool and title. I have updated the fiddle, check the fiddle you have shared! Also code for your reference!

CSS code:

```
.x-tool-after-title{
    top:auto !important;
}

.x-title-rotate-right{
    top:30px !important;
}
```

app.js:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        var mainView = new Ext.panel.Panel({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Container',
            layout: 'border',
            itemId: 'bigContainer',
            height: 300,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Left Panel',
                itemId: 'LeftPanel',
                region: 'west',
                width: 300,
                height: 900,
                collapsible: true,
                collapseMode: 'header',
                titleCollapse: true,
                split: true,
                flex: 1,
                scroll: false,
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Center',
                itemId: 'centerPanel',
                region: 'center',
                width: 300,
                height: 900,
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Right Panel',
                itemId: 'rightPanel',
                region: 'east',
                width: 300,
                height: 900,
                collapsible: true,
                collapseMode: 'header',
                titleCollapse: true,
                split: true,
                flex: 1,
                scroll: false,
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

    }
});
```